# SeekBar in android

Tags: android

I am trying to customize the seek bar by making it vertical and changing the progress and thumb image. But when I try to set the progress image, it shows a very thin image rather than a complete image. How this can be achieved?

XML File

```
 <com.example.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekbar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="116dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/panel"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb1" >
</com.example.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekbar>
```

Comment: could you provide your code and an illustration?

Comment: Change you question title name to "Vertical SeekBar in Android". It will help to others.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by customizing SeekBar.
Before customizing SeekBar you need to know about following

```
1.Layer List
2.Animation List
3.Selector
```

I have posted complete tutorial regard this have look [this](http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-android-seekbar-developement.html).
Hope this will help you lot.
For VerticalSeekBar use following code

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends AbsVerticalSeekBar {

    /**
     * A callback that notifies clients when the progress level has been
     * changed. This includes changes that were initiated by the user through a
     * touch gesture or arrow key/trackball as well as changes that were initiated
     * programmatically.
     */
    public interface OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        /**
         * Notification that the progress level has changed. Clients can use the fromUser parameter
         * to distinguish user-initiated changes from those that occurred programmatically.
         *
         * @param seekBar The SeekBar whose progress has changed
         * @param progress The current progress level. This will be in the range 0..max where max
         *        was set by {@link ProgressBar#setMax(int)}. (The default value for max is 100.)
         * @param fromUser True if the progress change was initiated by the user.
         */
        void onProgressChanged(VerticalSeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser);

        /**
         * Notification that the user has started a touch gesture. Clients may want to use this
         * to disable advancing the seekbar.
         * @param seekBar The SeekBar in which the touch gesture began
         */
        void onStartTrackingTouch(VerticalSeekBar seekBar);

        /**
         * Notification that the user has finished a touch gesture. Clients may want to use this
         * to re-enable advancing the seekbar.
         * @param seekBar The SeekBar in which the touch gesture began
         */
        void onStopTrackingTouch(VerticalSeekBar seekBar);
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekBarChangeListener;

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.seekBarStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser) {
        super.onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser);

        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, getProgress(), fromUser);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a listener to receive notifications of changes to the SeekBar's progress level. Also
     * provides notifications of when the user starts and stops a touch gesture within the SeekBar.
     *
     * @param l The seek bar notification listener
     *
     * @see SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
     */
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener l) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    void onStartTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void onStopTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Dipu. It was a good tutorial. But can you please explain me what all the image you referred to? like seekbar_total.9.png etc. and is it getting used somewhere in progress_horizontal.

Comment: yeah I have explained  there in brief read properly and study code too 1st for good knowledge and then start coding

Answer (score 0):

Use this customize SeekBar.

```
package com.tt.droidtracker.widget;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(),0);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int i=0;
            i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            setProgress(i);
            Log.i("Progress",getProgress()+"");
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

**This XML code use in XML along with your package name**

```
<com.tt.droidtracker.widget.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/img_seek_handler" />
```

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Accept as answer for others if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Hi Vishesh , I am able to turn by seekbar vertically, and kept my images in the res/drawable and refereed them similarly, but the seekbar is not increasing its height